# Typescript native shorthand for value dictionary

Tags: typescript

I just create a dictionary Interface like:

```
export default interface IDictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

where I'm able to declare variables like

```
const myDic1 = IDictionary<boolean>;
const myDic2 = IDictionary<number>;
```

But I would like to know if is there any other (more universal) notation in typescript that describe the same or similiar type of interface.

Or should I import my `IDictionary` in every project of mine.

Comment: I think the built in is `Map` as the below example: `const myDic1 = new Map<string, string>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predefined type `Record` can be used to obtain an equivalent type.

```
declare const myDic1: Record<string, boolean>;
declare const myDic2: Record<string, number>;
```

`Record` is usually used for more specific keys (ex: `Record<"key1" | "key2", boolean>`) but it works with string as well.